# Where to get linux "5.4.0-77-generic" kernel source?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, cross-compilation

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 on a qemu arm64 virtual machine. This is based on qemu's arm64 'virt' machine and I added a peripheral in the virtual machine. Now to test device driver, I need to build kernel module and I have to do it on my x86_64 ubuntu 20.04 machine.
Inside the VM, the `uname -r` command gives me `5.4.0-77-generic`. I learned that I need the kernel source for this version(or is only the kernel header enough? [this](https://blukat29.github.io/2017/12/cross-compile-arm-kernel-module/) says I need kernel source.) . I have had trouble downloading a specific kernel version in the past and now I'm not sure how I should get this version.
From https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+source/linux-signed I can see some `5.4.0-77.86` versions under `security` and `main` but I'm not sure how these versions are different from `5.4.0-77-generic`. Please anyone tell me how I can get this `5.4.0-77-generic` kernel version source. Step by step instruction will be appreciated but any comment is welcome. Thanks! (The kernel.org site shows only some selected or recent versions.)

ADD :
After `apt-cache search 5.4.0` I tried `sudo apt install linux-cloud-tools-5.4.0-77-generic` and it installs

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/linux-tools
/usr/lib/linux-tools/5.4.0-77-generic
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/linux-cloud-tools-5.4.0-77-generic
/usr/share/doc/linux-cloud-tools-5.4.0-77-generic/copyright
/usr/lib/linux-tools/5.4.0-77-generic/hv_fcopy_daemon
/usr/lib/linux-tools/5.4.0-77-generic/hv_kvp_daemon
/usr/lib/linux-tools/5.4.0-77-generic/hv_vss_daemon
/usr/lib/linux-tools/5.4.0-77-generic/lsvmbus
/usr/share/doc/linux-cloud-tools-5.4.0-77-generic/changelog.Debian.gz
```

I don't think this contains the kernel source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build a standalone kernel driver, you only need your kernel's header.
It can be installed throught the `linux-headers-5.4.0-77-generic` package.
Don't mind about what is on repository, just:

1. Make sure your package database is up-to-date by running as root `apt update`
2. Install the required package with, still as root, `apt install linux-headers-5.4.0-77-generic`.

Usually, on ubuntu based distros, you'll have:

- `linux-image-<version>`   : The kernel by itself.
- `linux-headers-<version>` : Kernel's header.
- `linux-source-<version>`  : Kernel's whole sources.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the very succinct and clear answer!

Comment: But how come in my ubuntu 20.04 machine, I see  `linux-headers-5.4.0-77-generic` and 
`linux-image-5.4.0-77-generic` for apt install candidates and not `linux-source-5.4.0-77-generic`? I see a candidate `linux-source-5.4.0 - Linux kernel source for version 5.4.0 with Ubuntu patches` which is the only source containing `5.4.0` pattern. (I understand I don't need the source).

Comment: I can't tell why the sources don't follow the same naming convention, nevertheless, `linux-source-5.4.0` actually fetch `5.4.0.77` sources as you can see there: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/linux-source-5.4.0

Comment: Oh, thanks so much again. I learned also that I have to check the package info at least :).

Comment: After installing the headers for 5.4, how do I boot into it?

Comment: One doesn't boot on headers. Headers are only used to compile kernel related code (ie: drivers).